# Union more than one object into one object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have two object returned from database, i want to union this object into one object, for example:

```
{
            "id": 4,
            "first_name": "s",
            "last_name": "a",
            "personal_no": "12",
            "email": "",
            "gender": "M",
            "address": "s",
            "birthdate": "a",
            "phone": "12"
        }
```

second one :

```
{
            "id": 684,
            "create_date": "2017-08-31T07:41:32.000Z",
            "update_date": null,
            "person_no": "",
            "status_id": 1,
            "payment_status_id": null,
            "payment_type": null,
            "comment": null,
            "res_type": null
        }
```

I want to get result like this

```
{
{
first object 
},
{
second object
}
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense; object properties must have names. You could make an array: `[{}, {}]` instead however.

Comment: you mean `[{first object },{second object}]`?

Comment: Do you want to get all properties into one object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an array to do this, and then use Object.assign() to convert it into an object

```js
let a = {
            "id": 4,
            "first_name": "aa",
            "last_name": "a",
            "personal_no": "a",
            "email": "a",
            "gender": "MALE",
            "address": "a",
            "birthdate": "2017-09-14T20:00:00.000Z",
            "phone": "a"
        };


let b = {
            "id": 684,
            "create_date": "2017-08-31T07:41:32.000Z",
            "update_date": null,
            "person_no": "a",
            "status_id": 1,
            "payment_status_id": null,
            "payment_type": null,
            "comment": null,
            "res_type": null
        }
let result = [a, b];
console.log(result);
let result2 = Object.assign({}, result);
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your expectation is as follows

```js
var data={
          "firstObject":{},
          "secondObject":{}
        };

data.firstObject={
            "id": 4,
            "first_name": "s",
            "last_name": "s",
            "personal_no": "1",
            "email": "a",
            "gender": "MALE",
            "address": "a",
            "birthdate": "a",
            "phone": "a"
          };


data.secondObject={
            "id": 684,
            "create_date": "a",
            "update_date": null,
            "person_no": "a",
            "status_id": 1,
            "payment_status_id": null,
            "payment_type": null,
            "comment": null,
            "res_type": null
        };
        
console.log(data.firstObject);
console.log(data.secondObject);
```